# Remove only a part of a string

Tags: java, string, split

If I have the following string:

```
< asd="testJava"><a href="/title/text/">BLA BLA <asddead>
```

How can I get only the string BLA BLA.

I tried split but it removes me all the chars, I need to remove only those from ">" to "<".
Once I get the string, I'm gonna add it to an `ArrayList` with `array.add();`
Can someone help me with the code that removes the strings?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it HTML? Is it some other XML?

Comment: Im gonna use that in Java. I need to remove the html code and conserve only the string.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to replace everything between `<` and `>` by nothing:

```
String newText = oldText.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
```

2 more notes:

1. This wouldn't work on something like `<a href="foo>com">BLA BLA</a>`, since regex would match the `>` in `foo>com` and not the corrent one. In such case, I would reccomend a proper HTML / XML parser.
2. add `.trim()` to erase any whitespaces before / after your text. Without it, `<img> <br> BLA BLA` would not resolve into `'BLA BLA'`, but `'  BLA BLA'`

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the implications of expanding this solution to a full HTML parser...
you could use replaceAll with a regex.

```
str = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","");
```

should replace all the html with nothing, leaving just your labelof BLABLA